# Weird LD_PRELOAD trick + gcc destructor behavior

Tags: c, gcc, environment-variables, destructor, ld-preload

I have recently learned the LD_PRELOAD trick ([What is the LD_PRELOAD trick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick)), which can be used to debug or patch the program.

I wanted to see if I could combine this trick and GCC destructor (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) to debug a variable, and created an extremely simple case to hone my understanding.

I have `test.c` as provided below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a = 1;
void __attribute__((destructor)) run_last() {
    printf("Destructor: %d\n", a);
}
```

and `test_2.c` as provided below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.c"

int main()
{
    extern int a;
    printf("main: %d\n", a++);
}
```

I compile `test.c` using the command `gcc -Wall -O3 -fPIC -shared test.c -o test.so` to generate the shared object, and compile `test_2.c` using the command `gcc test_2.c -o test_2`

Now, what I'm hoping to see is an output of:

```
main: 1
Destructor: 2
```

The reason for this expectation is because I have post-incremented the variable `a` after I printed the statement, and as I am using `extern int a`, as far as I understand, I am incrementing the variable `a` that was declared in the `test_2.c`, which contains the destructor function `run_last()` that will use the most updated value of `a`.

However, instead, I get an output such as this:
[image]

Why is there a `Destructor: 1` here? From my understanding, shouldn't the destructor only be called once? My guess at the moment is that when I `#include "test.c"` in the `test_2.c`, there is a behavior that I don't understand at the moment.

Thank you for any suggestions or guidance,

Comment: It's probably coming from some other program being invoked after your test program. Can you clarify exactly how you ran the test, whether you exported `LD_PRELOAD` explicitly or just by setting it at the beginning of the command? The screenshot is not clear, especially the odd bold-cyan `LD_PRELOAD` at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Thank you for your response @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE

Here is the exact step of how it has been done:

1. restart the computer

2. open the terminal

3. run `LD_PRELOAD=./test.so ./test_2`

Sorry for the confusion with the bold-cyan `LD_PRELOAD`, that is my directory name which I am using zsh to keep me on track of what directory I'm currently in. 

So the above output can be understood as the same as `$ LD_PRELOAD=./test.so ./test_2`

Comment: You have two `a` variables, one of them got incremented, both got printed. One instance of the variable and function comes from `#include "test.c"`, the other one from the preload.

Comment: @dratenik Ah so as I thought, it was indeed because of the statement `#include "test.c"`. I suppose I need to do some reverse engineering to find something in more detail because I didn't know that doing #include "*.c" creates another instance of process. Thank you for your response

Comment: `#include` is a pure text operation, it will insert the contents of test.c at that location, the compiler will then compile them as if they were also part of test_2.c.

Comment: @dratenik Thank you very much!